# How to get current bandwidth (download) speed ? 

Tags: delphi, indy

How to get current bandwith speed using IdTCPServer or IdTCPClient ?

I want to know, how fast client is downloading data from server ?

e.g.: Downloading speed: 450 kbps

Comment: Please don't put the tag information in the title of your question. It defeats the purpose of having tags in the first place, and makes the question topic longer and harder to read. Also, when you're using something like Indy, where there are major differences between versions, it helps if you include what version of the components you're using. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assign handlers to the `OnWorkBegin`, `OnWork`, and `OnWorkEnd` events of the connection's `TIdTCPConnection` object.  The `OnWorkBegin` event has an `AWorkCountMax` parameter that gives you the total expected bytes being transfered (if known ahead of time). The `OnWork` event has an `AWorkCount` parameter that gives you a running total of how many bytes have actually been transferred since the `OnWorkBegin` event was fired.

Whenever the `OnWork` event is fired, subtract the previous `AWorkCount` value from the current `AWorkCount` value to determine how many bytes have been transferred between the two events, and then divide that value by the amount of time that has elapsed between the two events.  With that final value, you can calculate b/sec, kb/sec, mb/sec, etc as needed.

Depending on how exactly you are sending/receiving your data, you may have to manually call the `BeginWork()` and `EndWork()` methods of `TIdTCPConnection` to get the `OnWork...` events to start firing.  Most of Indy's read/write methods do not call `Begin/EndWork()` internally.